# Temporarily disable a hook?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

Is it possible to temporarily disable a hook when running a mercurial command?  e.g., something like:

```
hg push --no-hook
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't disable a remote repository's hook. But you could enable or disable a local hook via `--config` option:

```
$ hg commit -m test --config 'hooks.commit.info=set | grep "^HG_"'
```

Answer (score 7):

According to [this](http://www.selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2011-December/036480.html) <s>bug</s>feature, the following skips local hooks:

```
hg --config alias._pull=pull _pull
```

Obviously this is a hack, but it has worked since 2011, and is the only way to skip local hooks given the lack of a '--no-hooks' option.

Comment: In case this wasn't obvious, replace all instances of `pull` with other commands (e.g. `commit`) to run those without their local hooks.

Comment: `hg --config alias.fpush=push fpush` doesn't appear to work. It's still running my `preoutgoing` hook.

Comment: @mpen, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14895026/1811525) - for obvious reasons you are not able to disable hooks on the remote side. That is why the hack can only work with `pull` and not `push`.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an `outgoing` or `preoutgoing` hook that is locally configured, you can disable it by commenting out its entry under `[hooks]` in `.hg/hgrc`. If this is a hook configured on the repository that you are pushing to (`changegroup`, `incoming`, `prechangegroup`, `pretxnchangegroup`), you will have to comment out its entry under `[hooks]` in the target repository's `.hg/hgrc` (if you have access to it).